# React and Django routing problem in media file

Tags: python, django, reactjs

When I am using `re_path('.*',index,name='index')` unable to route to my media locations and instead of `re_path` when i am using `path('/',index,name='index')` then my react app routing is not working.
so what should i do ?

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path , include,re_path
from .views import index
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/bookdetails/', include('backend.api.urls', 'api')),
    re_path('.*', index , name='index')
]
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns+=static(settings.STATIC_URL , document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns+= static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

setting.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "/static")
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "frontend/build/static")
]
MEDIA_URL = '/images/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'images')
```

The data form api is

```
{
    "user": "exist",
    "password": "valid",
    "userdetails": {
        "user_name": "laxman1006",
        "full_name": "ajay nagpal",
        "user_email": "Laxman@9451",
        "college_name": "iitd",
        "city": "luckonow",
        "country": "india",
        "profile_img": "/images/profile_image/laxman1006/laxman1006.jpg"
    }
}
```

This is my serializer

```
class UserdetailsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    '''user details seriailizer '''
    class Meta:
        model = Userinfo
        fields = ['user_name','full_name','user_email','college_name','city','country','profile_img']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed to this and now it is working
As that line was handling all of my url requests and my media files url was also handled by that so i just changed the sequence and now its working

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,include,re_path
from .views import index
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.conf import settings
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/bookdetails/', include('backend.api.urls', 'api')),
]
# urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,document_root= settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns+=static(settings.STATIC_URL , document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns+= static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
urlpatterns+= [re_path('.*', index , name='index')]
```

Answer (score 1):

Change it on your `settings.py` file and `urls.py` file as like below :

settings.py :

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '/static')
STATICFILES_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '/static')

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

urls.py :

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/bookdetails/', include('backend.api.urls', 'api')),
]


if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns+=static(settings.STATIC_URL , document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns+= static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

**Edited:**

Add this inside your model `UserInfo` :

models.py :

```
    def get_image_url(self):
        img = self.profile_img
        if img:
            return img.image.url
        else:
            return None
```

serializers.py :

```
class UserdetailsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    '''user details seriailizer '''
    profile_img = seriailizer.SerializerMethodField()
    class Meta:
        model = Userinfo
        fields = ['user_name','full_name','user_email','college_name','city','country','profile_img']


    def get_profile_img(self, obj):
        request = self.context.get('request')
        profile_img = obj.get_image_url()
        return request.build_absolute_uri(profile_img)
```

Comment: It worked for a second i don't know why but now same problem unable to load image whereas in my server log the response is 200

Comment: can you please share your api data ?

Comment: which api data ?

Comment: The data which you request for your `image`. Either It would be great if you can share the whole data that you're requesting as `http` protocol  in your `bookdetail` api.

Comment: Edited it I want to display the image i.e profile_img

Comment: When I am using re_path('.*',index,name='index') unable to route to my media locations and instead of re_path when i am using path('/',index,name='index') then my react app routing is not working.

Comment: Oh i got it! can you please add also the `serializers` of your api data in your questions?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220628/discussion-between-laxman-gupta-and-xxnora).